# How to save real time video stream and convert it to MP4 using Websocket and Javascript MediaRecorder API?

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, mediarecorder, getusermedia

I am trying to upload real time video stream using Javascript and .NET Web Socket. I am passing Base64 encoded data each second to web socket server where its appending data into a single file which is in webm format. At times video is not getting uploaded cause of unknown error or it gets partially uploaded. Can someone help with best approach to upload video on server real time and convert it to MP4 without paid third party tools. Am appending code I am using below-

```
//js code

var handleDataAvailable = function(event) {
      if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
          try{          
                var reader = new window.FileReader();                  
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                  var base64data = reader.result;
                  if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN){
                    ws.send(base64data);
                  }
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(event.data);            
          }catch(ex){

          }      
      }
    }
const SERVER_URL = "ws://localhost:5029";
var ws = new WebSocket(SERVER_URL);
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(outputStream, options);
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;

// C# code
// System.Net.WebSockets;
// websocket connection handling code
//

//on message event of websocket
public async Task OnMessage(string message)
{
    var base64Data = Regex.Match(message, @"data:video/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
    var ByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
    string path = "~//TempUploads//Recordings//test.webm";
    if (!Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));
    }

    using (var stream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path), FileMode.Append))
    {
      try
      {
        stream.Write(ByteArray, 0, ByteArray.Length);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {


      }

    }

}
```

Comment: for js you can checkout this lib https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC, you're not doing anything with `ws` please create snippet with complete code so someone can check what's wrong you're doing.

Comment: i am sending data using ws.send(base64data). see my javascript code snippet

Comment: @nickalchemist Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

For people who are struggling with similar issues with the MediaRecorder API, make sure that you check the following common points:

- You've actually started recording the stream using `mediaRecorder.start()`
- Try increasing the time period of data emission to >= 1.5s by passing it as a parameter to the `start()` method in milisecs, like so: `mediaRecorder.start(1500)`. This one gives your clientside more breathing room in between chunks, slows down the rate at which you emit data to your backend but it increases the chunk size.